# How can i get total base measurements in shopify theme file

Tags: shopify

I want to display "total base measurement" on the cart page. How can I achieve this one?

[image: sh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product measurements are part of [variant object](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/variant/#variant-unit_price). If your theme does not support this, you can follow this [Shopify guide](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/intro-to-shopify/initial-setup/sell-in-germany/price-per-unit#show-unit-prices-on-your-online-store) to display unit prices. However, latest Shopify supported themes display this information on Product as well as Cart pages. Relevant code snippet from [Shopify Debut theme](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/debut/styles/default), that shows unit prices on Cart page.

```
{%- comment -%}
    Markup template for unit price
{%- endcomment -%}
<div {% unless item.unit_price_measurement %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-unit-price-group>
    <dt>
        <span class="visually-hidden visually-hidden--inline">{{ 'products.product.unit_price_label' | t }}</span>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <span class="price-unit-price">
        {%- capture unit_price_separator -%}
            <span aria-hidden="true">/</span><span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.unit_price_separator' | t }}&nbsp;</span>
        {%- endcapture -%}
        {%- capture unit_price_base_unit -%}
            {%- if item.unit_price_measurement.reference_value != 1 -%}
                {{- item.unit_price_measurement.reference_value -}}
            {%- endif -%}
            {{ item.unit_price_measurement.reference_unit }}
        {%- endcapture -%}
            <span data-unit-price>{{ item.unit_price | money }}</span>{{- unit_price_separator -}}<span data-unit-price-base-unit>{{- unit_price_base_unit -}}</span>
        </span>
    </dd>
 </div>
```

This is how the Cart page looks

[image]

Comment: thanks, @bilal but I need to display like this $0.88 / unit

Comment: If you need the word **unit** regardless of unit, simply change the last `{{- unit_price_base_unit -}}` to _unit_